# Colimit of Covariant hom functor is a singleton.

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $J$ is small, and let $[k,-]:J\rightarrow Set $ be the usual $\hom $ functor. I want to prove that the colimit of the diagram $\left ( [k,j]\right )_{j\in J}$ is a one-point set.

As a first try, I thought the Yoneda Lemma would apply and so I took a singleton $*$  in $Set$ and then given a cocone $\left ( \lambda _{j},X \right )_{j\in J}$ tried to use Yoneda to find the unique $h:*\rightarrow X$ with the required property. I have not been able to do find such an $h$ however.

Next, I tried to do this naively using the construction of the colimit in $Set$ by coproducts and coequalizers:

If $\alpha :j\rightarrow i$, take

$\coprod _{\alpha :j\rightarrow i}[k,j];\ \overline i_{\alpha }:[k,j]\mapsto\coprod _{\alpha :j\rightarrow i}[k,j] $,

$\coprod _{j\in J}[k,j];\ i_{j}:[k,j]\mapsto \coprod _{j\in J}[k,j] $, where $\overline i_\alpha $ and $i_j$ are the injections.

Then the UMP of the coproduct implies that there are arrows

$\phi ,\psi :\coprod _{\alpha :j\rightarrow i}[k,j]\rightarrow \coprod _{j\in J}[k,j]$ s.t.

$\phi \circ \overline i_\alpha =i_{dom \alpha }\ $ and $\psi \circ \overline i_\alpha =i_{codom \alpha }\circ [k,\alpha ]$.

I then take the coequalizer of $\phi $ and $\psi $, which is

$\coprod _{j\in J}[k,j]/\sim $ where $\sim $ is the minimal equivalence relation containing the pairs $\left ( \phi \left ( [k,j],\alpha  \right ), \psi \left ( [k,j],\alpha  \right )\right )$.

So I need to prove that there is only one equivalence class. I think Yoneda can ve used here as well. A hint would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F (-) = \mathcal{J} (k, -)$. Then:
$$\mathbf{Set} (\varinjlim\nolimits_\mathcal{J} F, X) \cong [\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Set}] (F, \Delta X) \cong X \cong \mathbf{Set} (1, X)$$
Hence, $\varinjlim\nolimits_\mathcal{J} F \cong 1$.

Comment: Well, that was easy enough. Nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(-) = \mathcal J(k,-)$ and let's go back to your direct calculation of the colimit in $\mathsf{Set}$.

The colimit of $F \colon \mathcal J \to \mathsf{Set}$ is given by
$$ \operatorname{colim}F \simeq \coprod_{j\in \mathcal J}F(j) \big/ {\sim} $$
where $\sim$ identifies $x \in F(j)$ with $F(f)(x) \in F(j')$ for any $f\colon j\to j'$ in $\mathcal J$.

But there $F(j) = \mathcal J(k,j)$ and $F(f\colon j \to j') = (g \mapsto f\circ g)$, so in particular the equivalence relation $\sim$ identifies $\mathrm{id}_k \colon k \to k$ to $F(f)(\mathrm{id}_k)=f$ for any $f\colon k \to j$. So indeed there is a unique equivalence class in your coequalizer.

---

Remark that with this proof in mind, you can now easily see why a cocone $(\lambda_j, X)_{j\in\mathcal J}$ over $F$ is actually just the choice of an element in $X$, namely the image of $\mathrm{id}_k$ by $\lambda_k$.

Comment: A more sophisticated version of this would be the observation that $\varinjlim F$ is the set of connected components of the category of elements of $F$, which has an initial object.

Comment: @Pece: I see. Thanks for the very lucid explanation of this.

Comment: @Zhen: if I understand you, you sayng that since $*\mapsto id_{k}$ is initial in $\left ( *\downarrow [k,-] \right )$, there is only one connected component. And in general,  $\varinjlim_j F_j$ is the set of equivalence classes as noted above and these in turn are the  connected components of the comma category. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.